# Displaying test results in a better way in Azure DevOps with Pipelines

Tags: testing, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

Azure Pipelines has a way of displaying test results after builds, [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops). This seems to be very limited, however, and doesn't display much of the stuff we want.

We're using NUnit 3 with a .NET Core project, and NUnit outputs a bunch of stuff for test results. We specifically want to display FQN of the test at a minimum, but being able to easily view tests by category would suffice as well. This doesn't seem to be possible with the default Tests tab.

My question: Does DevOps support doing something like this or do I need to make my own site/API for viewing test results? I'm open to pretty much anything, we just want to avoid anything that requires manual offline processing.

Comment: I am afraid azure devops doesnot support above currently. You can try creating your own [test results extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops), or you can [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(select suggest a feature and choose azure devops)

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Alright, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Microsoft comment to the question, this is not currently possible. I added a suggestion on their tracker [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/901617/display-more-useful-information-with-test-results.html).